# Debugging Console App and Web API App from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

**Problem**

I have a `Visual Studio 2010` solution that contains various `class library` projects, 1 `ASP.NET Web API` project and 2 `Console Application` projects.

Now the console applications use the `WebClient` class to communicate with the Web API project I have within the Solution. When I run one of the console applications, the Web API is automatically run within the VS ASP.NET WebDev Server (within Localhost). This is fine. When I set breakpoints within the Web API solution (say one of the controllers), they are not hit during debugging. Only the console breakpoints are hit. Now if I run the Web API solution directly, and use something like [REST Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/rest-easy/) FF addon to build the request, the breakpoints are hit.

Is there a option in Visual Studio 2010 to break across two different applications at once when debugging?

**Technology I'm using**

1. Visual Studio 2010 SP1
2. Console applications are .NET 4.0 projects
3. Web API project is the 1st release

Comment: Are you able to open two instances of Visual Studio and run both applications separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of several methods to cope with your question:

1. explicitly load the symbols from Solution A:
    go to **Tools**->**Options**->**Debugging**->**Symbols** you can point it at the .pdb file from Solution A.
   Then you can see if the symbols are loaded from your binaries by going to **Debug**->**Windows**->**Modules** while debugging.
2. Disable the Debugging feature named "Just My Code". This is a feature aimed at minimizing the debugging experience to just the code in your solution. In order to disable it:

Tools -> Options -> Debugging

Unchecked "Enable Just My Code"

3. Last option is using the solution I've found in a different question someone posted:

> Here is what I did.
>
> Say a project from solution A refers a project from Solution B and I
>   want to debug into solution B project from Solution A project.
>
> Open Solution B in Visual Studio. Set the project properties to "Use
>   Local IIS Wb Server", set the project Url and create Virtual
>   Directory.
>
> Open Solution A in another Visual Studio Instance. Set the project
>   properties to "Use Local IIS Wb Server" and Check "Use IIS Express",
>   set the project Url and create Virtual Directory.
>
> Press F5 and start debugging Solution B instance of Visual Studio.
>   Then Press F5 and start debugging Solution A instance of Visual
>   Studio. Now both the instances of Visual Studio will be in debug mode.
>   Start from Solution A now and you should be able to debug into
>   Solution B just like if both projects were in the same solution.
>
> The key here is to "Use IIS express" for one and "Local IIS Web
>   server" for the other project. This will let you have two debuggers
>   running at once.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25630033/3125120

I hope it helps.

Comment: I havent forgotton about this and will be trialling tonight.